# Limit the Length of TextView

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Limit text length of EditText in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285412/limit-text-length-of-edittext-in-android)

I am a textView on Activity, which is being displayed as per the parameter it is receiving from the JSON response, I need to restrict it to 12 characters only.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/includeheadersetting"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Use `android:maxLength="12"` to limit the text length

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/includeheadersetting"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Name"
            android:maxLength="12"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

You can also use another property as follows:

```
android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"
```

Using this property **"..."** will be added end of the text as follows:

**"Hello How are ..."** instead of **"Hello How are you?"**

Comment: line 1: "hello how are"
line 2 :"you"
 instaed of hello how are you

Comment: android:singleLine="true" is deprecated. You have to used android:maxLines="1" instead

Answer (score 7):

Generally speaking only including `android:maxLength` is not considered good idea.

Use maxLength attribute, then use the `android:ellipsize="marquee"` to add a "..." automatically to the end of any line that has been cut-off.

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/txtView" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:maxLines="1" 
    android:maxLength="10" 
    android:ellipsize="marquee"/>
```

Comment: android:ellipsize="end" add a "..." not "marequee".
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20511174/2469427

Answer (score 1):

add code like

```
android:maxLength="12"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following max length parameter to your text view-

```
android:maxLength="12"
```

whatever the limit you want you can replace that like instead of 12 can give 14 or whatever length you want.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:maxLength="12"` to your text view..

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/includeheadersetting"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:maxLength="12" />
```