# How to give limit for TextView Android

Tags: android, textview

I need help.I have a TextView and wanna give limit to my TextView.However,I use maxLength , maxLine and ellipsize.There aren't give any result.Here is my code :

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/introTextNews"
        style="@style/FormtTextStyle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtNewsName"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:ellipsize="end"/>
```

Comment: `android:singleLine="true"` and `android:ems="9"`

Comment: is maxLength not doing what you want? please give more details

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120397/limit-the-length-of-textview ?

Comment: thank you for response it's work right now.