# how can i count the character limit of TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-edittext

I want to count the total number of characters a TextView can hold with 14dp text size and 100dp of width and with 100dp of height. then I have to add those characters' limits to an EditText.

```
 <TextView
                android:id="@+id/OFSO_text1"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center"
                android:fontFamily="@font/lato_bold"
                android:gravity="center|bottom"
                android:text="SEASONAL DISCOUNT ARE HERE"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/lightcream"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:autoSizeTextType="none"
               />
```

I have tried this code but this is not working properly. this provides me more char limit then this Textview can holds.

```
            TextPaint paint = textView.getPaint();
            int wordwidth=(int)paint.measureText("a",0,1);
            int screenwidth = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
            int  maxLength = screenwidth/wordwidth;
```

please help me out!! thanks in advance. 
happy coding!!!

Comment: try OFSO_text1.getText().toString().length(); and store it into variable

Comment: TextSize Should be in SP ..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit the Length of TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13120397/limit-the-length-of-textview)

Comment: @Niceumang I don't want to count string char, I want to add more text to this TextView but before that, I need to know how many more char this text view can hold? got my point?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing font size and typeface in your measurements.

```
        // In case you are storing your font in res/font
        Typeface typeface = ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.noto_sans_regular);
        paint.setTypeface = typeface
        paint.setTextSize = sizeOfYourFontInPixels
```

Comment: As I understand from your code it is - lato_bold `R.font. lato_bold`

Comment: still counting more char than textview limit

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your textholder size varies from device to device,
And for the count, you can do something like,

```
    int textLenght = yourtText.getText().toString().lenght();
    if(textLenght>n) {
    yourEditText.setText(yourText);}
```

Comment: no!! i want to count how many char, a text view can hold with specific height and width

Comment: Check my recent answer

Answer (score 0):

Measuring Text: You can do something like this :

```
float textWidth = textView.getPaint().measureText(textView.getText().toString());

if(textView.getMeasureWidth() == n) {

Log.i("Text_count",textView.getText().toString().lenght());

}
```

or

```
if(textWidth == n) {
Log.i("Text_count",textView.getText().toString().lenght());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Add `addTextChangedListener` to the edittext for reading characters.
2. In override methods `beforeTextChanged`, `onTextChanged` and `afterTextChanged`, read characters like below

   ```
   int length = etText.length();
   int leftCharacters = 500 - length; //let default length of edittext is 500
   ```

Hope, it works for you!!